# devise simple registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, registration, devise

The user fills in the form his email and password.
After submiting the form, the user recieves an email, containing a activation link.
After clicking on that link, he comes to an form, where he can fill out the rest of his data (login, gender, age and so on...), before he does'nt correctly fills out the form, he is not allowed to log in.

How I can accomplish this scenario ?

Comment: This smells like homework. In any case, tell us what your thoughts are so far, any code you've written and people can advise.

Comment: Not really, I want migrate from Authlogic, and please dont't make me laugh, where are You getting such homework ?! The main problem is on validation of attributes, on update and create, and on redirecting after this actions, I have trouble make validations work with update password function and change profile too, the wiki on github is nice, but it does'nt really helped me

Comment: I love StackOverflow and you may well get a good answer here, but I wanted to make sure that you are aware there is a pretty active Good group devoted to Devise. You may want to post this question there. You can find it here: http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise?pli=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find what you are looking for in the screencasts and the text versions of the screencasts. The first one is Introducing Devise, and the second one is Customizing Devise:

**Introducing Devise**

Video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Text: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

**Customizing Devise**

Video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

Text: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise